# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present. (But Read() was called)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Sometimes SqlDataReader throws InvalidOperationException on .GetValue().

(Invalid attempt to read when no data is present).
Similar questions on stack doesn't have .Read() in code, but mine has.

Table1 always contains data, it has rows updated/inserted by other apps, but rows are never deleted.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(s))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE1", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    reader.Read();
                    var globalTimestamp = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0); //Sometimes throws
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is used in multithreaded apps.

I reproduced this in Parrallel.ForEach:
(using connectionstring with MaxPoolSize 1)

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, (_, __) =>
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(s))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(/*same query*/, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                {
                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    reader.Read();
                    var globalTimestamp = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0); //threw once, after timeout in another thread.
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I suspect problems with leaked SqlReader in another threads, that corrupt underlying sqlconnection. But i don't know if it is a problem here.

Maybe some of you had sililar issues, and have any ideas what can be done to avoid this problem.

(SqlReader has _sharedState._dataReady = false, and loaded _metadata)

Comment: Probably GetValue(0) is System.DBNull from reader.  May pre-check by if( reader.GetValue(0) is System.DBNull)

Comment: exception is from GetValue -> CheckIfDataIsReady() to be precise.
Database has this data, and this data is not null.  While using Parallel, this app has exclusive access to database. Nothing else could change this data,

Comment: Aside... SqlDataReaders are IDisposable, too. i.e.: you should be utilizing them in using blocks.